# page does not render on successful AJAX post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I'm having trouble linking my js front-end to my Node/Express back-end. When I make a request to my server from my client-side js, my requests return successful but the page I request does not render.

Server side I have:

```
app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => res.render('dashboard/dashboard', { updates, agendaItems }));
```

Client side:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/dashboard',
    data: context,
    success: function () {
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        console.log(textStatus);
    }
});
```

I get no errors and I do get the console.log('success') showing up in my console. When I go to http://localhost:27017/dashboard or I make the get request in Postman my routing does work as expected. The only problem I have is making a route request from my client-side js. I am making the ajax request on a button click.

Comment: I didn't post more code because it is a pretty massive and complex code base. There is a file under dashboard/dashboard - like I said, if I make the same get request by going to localhost/dashboard the page does render. The back-end works perfectly (which I know from making the requests in postman as well), so I am pretty sure the problem is in linking my front-end js to my Express server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term 'ajax' refers to 'asynchronous javascript and xml' (kind of a silly name imho). This is an http request which can be made from the code running in a webpage. The page's code is responsible for handling the response - the browser will not do anything with it by default.

This is in contrast to redirecting the browser which directs the browser to make a request and handle the response by parsing and rendering it etc.

The success function in your ajax() call could be used to parse and display the response if required, but would require more work and usually its easier to organise your application to use as much of the browser's default behaviour as possible.

Directing the browser to redirect the user would achieve this:

```
window.location = "/dashboard";
```

Comment: While that does work as an easy solution, I'm looking for more of an insight into why my ajax requests don't work as expected.

Comment: updated with some context. essentially if you use ajax you are responsible for handling the response. these days its mostly used for transferring data which is then templated into html for display, rather than transferring html.

Comment: Thanks, your extra information does clarify some things. I used your suggestion and use window.location to redirect on my success case so I can still make some database queries with my requests. It works as expected now.